# I couldn't understand how to put right indexing for 3d array

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import random
m,n,p=5,5,4
arr=np.zeros((p,n,m))

def insertingArray(arr):
    for k in range(p):
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(n):
                arr[i][j][k]=random.randint(1,10)

    
    

insertingArray(arr)
print(arr)
```

This is the output after running.

[image: 1]

Comment: It's `[i,j,k]` for a Numpy array.

Comment: i have tried the same as well. Still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confused with the sizes so you get index out of range error

try:

```
import numpy as np
import random
m,n,p=5,5,4
arr=np.zeros((p,n,m))

def insertingArray(arr):
    for k in range(p):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                arr[k][i][j]=random.randint(1,10)

    
    

insertingArray(arr)
print(arr)
```

Comment: Great.  The order of the loops and the indexs matter so you can avoid index out of range errors. If it solve your question please accept my answer.